# How to get proper(decode) manufacturer advertisement data from ble devices?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

i am new to android so,basically i am developing an app which get's the data from ble devices to do further operations over it.
What i have done until now :-

i scanned the devices got their rssi and macaddress,but when i tried to get the scanRecord in the callback method,to access the manufacturer data i got sparseArray like this:-

```
{89=[-128,42, 75, -112, 75, -34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -81, 22]}
```

but what i want it like this,

```
[59,00,80,BC,26,01,00,FF,FF,00,00,04,00,00,00]
```

Comment: You are getting the correct data, it's just the matter of formatting when printing it out.

Comment: can you please tell me how can i format it

Comment: This is actually a separate question - which has been asked many times here. Try to search how to convert a byte array to hexstring.

Comment: i solved it thank you for your time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Is solved it by following steps:-

I get the manufacturer data by passing the manufacturer id

> getScanRecord().getManufacturerSpecificData(manufacturerId)
>
> Which returns the byte array which afterwards i convert it to the hex
>   string by writing my own function and that's it